# Hadoop - Mkdirs failed to create C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\hadoop-unjar778 7707269774970262\META-INF\license

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I installed Hadoop on a Windows machine in pseudo-distributed mode and tried to run a MapReduce job on it. The Namenode and Datanode ran without any problems, however, the MapReduce job kept failing with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\hadoop-unjar778
7707269774970262\META-INF\license
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.ensureDirectory(RunJar.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:209)
```

I've checked that I already have full permission to that folder, and I also tried using maven-shade-plugin with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue but there are some todo

1. verify the folder permission with proper user for Temp\hadoop-unjar778
   7707269774970262\META-INF  (Can use chmod -R 777)
2. Check Namenode is running while executing MR
3. Node Managger service is running
4. Check the configuration:

For Hadoop 1.x:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9101</value>
  </property
```

For Hadoop 2.x:

> ```
> <property>
>     <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
>     <value>localhost:9101</value>
>   </property>
> ```